# Handling collection updates with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections

I have a collection of custom objects and I'd like to persist it in the easiest way using JPA.

My `CustomObject` class is mapped to a table. Now I'm wondering if JPA provides some kind of utility to handle object collection.

In particular I'd like to add or remove objects to/from my collection and then pass to a `save(Collection<CustomObject> cco)` method without checking which objects have changed (which of them I need to add and which to remove...)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for something in [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) which will save or update a collection, the answer is no. You will have to loop and do a save or update.

If you use [`EntityManager.merge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) API it will update if record is existing or else will insert a new record.

As far as delete is concerned, how will JPA or any other ORM determine that you want to delete that instance, if its a soft delete like updating a column like `is_active` to `true/false`, then yes by calling merge it can be done, but if you want a hard delete then JPA won't be able to determine by itself, you will have to do it manually.

Comment: +1 The deleting part is the one that gets tricky, you should have some sort of metadata for your objects (or another list and maintain a relationship through the indexes) to know which ones should be updated and which ones should be deleted.

Comment: Yep, deletion cannot be done that easy, mapping has to be there somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Brief explanation : so I have users and their corresponding rights. I want to be able to maintain my database with those information.

This is a solution I use :

**Beans :**

```
...
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idu", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Userrights> userRightsList;
...
}


...
@Entity
public class Userrights implements Serializable {
...
@JoinColumn(name = "idu", referencedColumnName = "idu")
@ManyToOne
private User idu;
...
}
```

**Spring :**

```
@Component
public class UserBean implements IUser {

    @Autowired
    private MyPersistenceContext<User> pc;
    ...
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void update(User user) throws Exception {
        pc.update(user, UPDATE_ERR);
    }
    ...
}

@Component
public class MyPersistenceContext<T> {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager EM;
    ...
    public void insert(T object, String errMsg) {
        EM.persist(object);
    }
    public void update(T object, String errMsg) {
        EM.merge(object);
    }
...
}

public void delete(T object, String errMsg) {
    T forDeletion = null;

    if (!EM.contains(object)) {
        forDeletion = EM.merge(object);
    }

    if (forDeletion != null) {
        EM.remove(forDeletion);
    }
}
```

**Test :**

```
@Test
public void testDb_InsertOrUpdateOfExistinguserRights() throws Exception {
        User u = null;
        try {
            u = IAS.DS().user().getByUsername("kor1 username");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        List<Userrights> lur = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean newUser = true;

        if (u != null) {
            newUser = false;
            lur = IAS.DS().userRights().get(u);
        } else {
            u = new User("kor1", "kor1 prezime", "kor1 username", "kor1 pass");
        }

        if (lur.isEmpty()) {
            lur.add(new Userrights(u, IAS.DS().roles().get(1)));
            lur.add(new Userrights(u, IAS.DS().roles().get(2)));
            lur.add(new Userrights(u, IAS.DS().roles().get(4)));
        } else {
            lur.clear();
            lur.add(new Userrights(u, IAS.DS().roles().get(1)));
            lur.add(new Userrights(u, IAS.DS().roles().get(5)));
        }

        u.setUserRightsList(lur);
        if (!newUser) {
            IAS.DS().user().update(u);
        } else {
            IAS.DS().user().insert(u);
        }
    }
```