# Entity Merge using Cascade.ALL OnetoMany relationship not inserting records for children

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, cuba-platform

I already looked at previous questions but all the solutions still doesn't work on my project.

I have a CUBA Platform project that uses spring core 5.2.3. CUBA uses the ORM implementation based on the EclipseLink framework.

I have 1 MainClass Entity, and children, SubClass Entity.

MainClass Definition

```
//annotations here
public class MainClass{

    @Composition
    @OnDelete(DeletePolicy.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainClass", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    protected List<SubClass> subClass;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
}
```

//SubClass entity

```
//annotations here
public class SubClass{

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAINCLASS_ID")
    protected MainClass mainClass;
}
```

The problem with this setup is that it only saves the MainClass Entity but not the SubClass Entity.

Service Class

```
@Service("MainService")
public class ServiceClass{

    @Inject
    private Persistence persistence;


    @Transactional
    public void saveOrUpdateMain(MainClass mainClass){

       MainClass qMainClass = (MainClass) entityManager.createQuery("select 
           b from main_Class b where b.extID = ?1")
                    .setParameter(1, extID).getSingleResult();

      //assume mainClass is not null, set the primary key of qMainClass to mainClass
      
      mainClass.setId(qMainClass.getId());
      
      entityManager.merge(mainClass);
     

    }


}
```

I have read this 2 links but still did not solve my issue.

[Why merging is not cascaded on a one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153237/why-merging-is-not-cascaded-on-a-one-to-many-relationship)

[JPA does not insert new childs from one to many relationship when we use merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782167/jpa-does-not-insert-new-childs-from-one-to-many-relationship-when-we-use-merge)

Comment: Which ORM implementation do you use at runtime and in which version? Please add that information to the question, so others have a chance to reproduce your setup (problem) correctly.

Comment: Show the code that performs the saving of the entities

Comment: I have updated the question. CUBA uses the ORM implementation based on the EclipseLink framework. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In CUBA, [DataManager](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/dataManager.html) is a preferred option to work with data. It automatically resolves cascade operations and does not require explicit transaction definition. Please try to implement this logic using DataManager first.